# How can I ensure that a join table is referencing two tables with a composite FK, one of the two column being in common on both tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables : `employee`, `event`, and these are N-N so the 3rd table `employee_event`.

The trick is, they can only N-N within the same `group`

```
employee
+---------+--------------+
| id      | group        |
+---------+--------------+
| 1       |        A     |
| 2       |        B     |
+---------+--------------+
```

```
event
+---------+--------------+
| id      | group        |
+---------+--------------+
| 43      |        A     |
| 44      |        B     |
+----
```

```
employee_event
+---------+--------------+
| employee_id | event_id     |
+-------------+--------------+
| 1           |       43     |
| 2           |       44     |
+---------+--------------+
```

So the combination `employee_id=1` `event_id=44` should not be possible, because employee from group A can not attend an event from group B. How can I secure my DB with this?

My first idea is to add the column `employee_event.group` so that I can make my two FK (composite) with `employee_id + group` and `event_id + group` respectively to the table `employee` and `event`. But is there a way to avoid adding a column in the join table for the only purpose of FKs?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You may create a function and use it as a check constraint on table `employee_event`.

```sql
create or replace function groups_match (employee_id integer, event_id integer)
returns boolean language sql as
$$
select 
 (select group from employee where id = employee_id) =
 (select group from event where id = event_id);
$$;
```

and then add a `check` constraint on table `employee_event`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee_event
ADD CONSTRAINT groups_match_check 
CHECK groups_match(employee_id, event_id);
```

Still bear in mind that rows in `employee_event` that used to be valid may become invalid but still remain intact if certain changes in tables `employee` and `event` occur.